# How does Rust deal with the intermediate value in a single expression that creates a reference-to-reference?

Tags: rust

I was playing around with pointers and references in Rust and noticed you can create a pointer-to-pointer or reference-to-reference in a single expression:

```
let i = 0;
let irr = &(&i);
let ipp: *const *const i32 = &(&i as *const i32);
```

If I was to try something similar in C, I would get a compile error because the 'addressof' operator returns an rvalue which doesn't have a storage location so cannot be pointed to:

```
int i = 0;
int *ip = &i;
int **ipp = &ip;
int **ipp = &(&i); /* error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'int *' */
```

How does Rust deal with the intermediate pointer/reference? Does it silently put it on the stack or is there some other magic going on?

Comment: I believe your question to already be answered by [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain why it is different.

Comment: @Shepmaster. Yes, thank you. The specifics of my question were answered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47663168/2996594) on the question you linked