# Confused by "temporary value dropped here while still borrowed"

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm confused by this error message about the type `&str`:

```
let a = &String::from("abcdefg"); // ok!
let a = String::from("abcdefg").as_str(); // compile error
```

The error:

```
let a = String::from("abcdefg").as_str();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
temporary value does not live long enough
```

I understand that in the second line, the `String` object is a temporary object, it drops when the line is over. But why does the first line run ok?

Comment: I asked a concise Question for this common rust error `error[E0716]` [error E0716: temporary value dropped while borrowed (rust)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626083/error-e0716-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed-rust)