# What are the semantics of mutably borrowing a literal in Rust?

Tags: rust, semantics, literals, borrowing

I found that this is able to compile:

```
let x = &mut 10;
*x = 20;
```

This is very confusing. What are the semantics of mutably borrowing an literal?

I come from C++, where the compiler will definitely not allow me to refer to a rvalue like this:

```cpp
int *x = &10;
int &y = 10;
```

Comment: @Boiethios I don't think it's a duplicate. It's related, absolutely. But the questions are different.

Comment: The fun is that in C, this `#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *p = &(int){ 10 };
    *p = 20;
    printf("%d", *p);
}` is allowed.

Comment: See also [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/155423)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like C++, Rust has the concept of rvalues and lvalue. The reference calls them *value expressions* (rvalue) and *place expressions* (lvalue). Additionally, there are *value contexts* and *place contexts* (slots inside of expressions/statements where a value expression or place expression, respectively, is expected).

**Rust has special rules for when a value expression (like a literal) is used in a place context (like the borrow operator `&`)**. From [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes):

> When using a value expression in most place expression contexts, a temporary unnamed memory location is created initialized to that value and the expression evaluates to that location instead [...].

So Rust automatically stores your value `10` in a memory location. The lifetime of the memory location varies depending on *how* the value expression is used, but in your case, the unnamed memory location has the same lifetime as the enclosing block. It thus is equivalent to a hidden `let` binding:

```
let _compiler_generated = 10;
let x = &mut _compiler_generated;
*x = 20;
```

This doesn't just work with literals:

```
fn get_u32() -> u32 { 3 }

let x = &mut get_u32();
*x = 20;
```

While being confusing to those familiar with how lifetimes of objects work in languages like C++, this is a fairly useful feature in a few situations.

---

Related: if you use an **im**mutable reference to a literal, the value is not just written to a stack slot, but into static memory. Meaning that `let _: &'static u32 = &10` is valid! This has been specified in [RFC 1414](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.md).

Comment: C++ does similar things sometimes as well, though the rules are slightly different.

Comment: @Veedrac I can only think of the special rule when const references are passed to functions (which then makes the reference last for the duration of the function call). Are there more rules?

Comment: `const T &x = get_value();` gets extended as well. Supposedly `const T &&x = get_value();` also works!

Comment: [This](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension) also documents the behavior described here.