# Why does function pointer behaviour differ in Rust depending on the mutability of the function pointer?

Tags: function, rust, ffi

When storing raw pointers to functions in structs in Rust, the behaviour of the program can change in unexpected ways depending on the mutability of the raw pointer.

Using `const` pointers gives the expected result.

The following code can also be viewed on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=753332583d84dbba9e2d88c66ea7c07c):

```rust
type ExternFn = unsafe extern "C" fn() -> ();

unsafe extern "C" fn test_fn() {
    println!("Hello!");
}

mod mut_ptr {
    use super::{ExternFn, test_fn};

    #[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
    pub struct FunctionHolder {
        function: *mut ExternFn,
    }

    impl FunctionHolder {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            FunctionHolder {
                function: (&mut (test_fn as ExternFn) as *mut _),
            }
        }

        pub fn call(&self) {
            if !self.function.is_null() {
                unsafe { (&*self.function)(); }
            }
        }
    }
}

mod const_ptr {
    use super::{ExternFn, test_fn};
    #[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
    pub struct FunctionHolder {
        function: *const ExternFn,
    }

    impl FunctionHolder {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            FunctionHolder {
                function: (&(test_fn as ExternFn) as *const _),
            }
        }

        pub fn call(&self) {
            if !self.function.is_null() {
                unsafe { (&*self.function)(); }
            }
        }
    }
}

// use const_ptr::FunctionHolder;
use mut_ptr::FunctionHolder;

fn check_holder(holder: &FunctionHolder) -> bool {
    let good = FunctionHolder::new();
    println!("parameter = {:#?}", holder);
    println!("expected = {:#?}", good);
    holder == &good
}

fn main() {
    let f0 = FunctionHolder::new();
    println!("{:?}", f0);

    let f1 = FunctionHolder::new();
    println!("{:?}", f1);

    // uncomment this line to cause a segfault if using the
    // mut_ptr version :-(
    // f1.call(); 

    assert!(check_holder(&f1));
}
```

In the `const_ptr` module, the code behaves as expected: The pointer value stored in the `FunctionHolder` struct is the same regardless of where the function is called, and using the `FunctionHolder::call` method calls the function as required.

In the `mut_ptr` module, there are some unexpected differences:

- The `FunctionHolder::new` method returns a struct holding a different value depending on the function in which it is called,
- The `FunctionHolder::call` method causes a segfault.

Comment: I don't fully understand this issue, but I'm guessing that taking a `&mut` of an external function is somewhat making a temporary variable and returning the address of that variable. If that is the case 'd say that this is a compiler bug, although I don't know if taking a `*mut` to code is well defined to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I think that's probably it - in [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c4733b24c3adb25e84675b9ec3b80940), taking an immutable reference to a function pointer returns the same address each time, whereas taking a mutable reference gives a different address each time. I'm guessing that the mutable reference operator creates a new temporary function on the stack, which is then used - that would explain the segfaults as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fn() -> ()` is a function pointer. `*const fn() -> ()` and `*mut fn() -> ()` are *function pointer pointers*.

You want to use much simpler code, which also means there's no difference between the two implementations:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct FunctionHolder {
    function: Option<ExternFn>,
}

impl FunctionHolder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        FunctionHolder {
            function: Some(test_fn as ExternFn),
        }
    }

    pub fn call(&self) {
        if let Some(f) = self.function {
            unsafe { f(); }
        }
    }
}
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, taking a mutable reference to a literal value constructs a new value each time:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{:p}", &42);
    println!("{:p}", &42);
    println!("{:p}", &42);

    println!("{:p}", &mut 42);
    println!("{:p}", &mut 42);
    println!("{:p}", &mut 42);
}
```

```
0x55a551c03a34
0x55a551c03a34
0x55a551c03a34
0x7ffd40dbb95c
0x7ffd40dbb9bc
0x7ffd40dbba1c
```

Immutable references to literals have implicit `static` promotion:

```
let a = &42;
// More-or-less
static HIDDEN: i32 = 42;
let a = &HIDDEN;
```

Mutable references to literals desugar to effectively:

```
let mut hidden: i32 = 42;
let a = &mut hidden;
```

By using raw pointers, you lose the support of the borrow checker to point out that your references don't live long enough for the mutable case.

See also:

- [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/155423)
- [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50345139/155423)
- [What are the semantics of mutably borrowing a literal in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51344979/155423)