# Rust reference to temporary value doesn't report error

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum List<'a> {
    Nil,
    Cons(i32, &'a List<'a>)
}

{
    let x = Cons(1, &Cons(2, &Nil));
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

It works fine. I don't understand why this code doesn't report any error, isn't the `Cons(2, &Nil)` dropped before constructing `Cons(1, _)` ?

Moreover, after I added an empty `impl Drop` for `List`, the above code doesn't work any more:

```
impl<'a> Drop for List<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {

    }
}
```

It reports errors that `borrowed value does not live long enough` for `Cons(2, _)` and `Nil`.

Why is there such difference between before and after adding `impl Drop` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't the `Cons(2, &Nil)` dropped before constructing `Cons(1, _)`?

If you bind a reference to a temporary, Rust extends the lifetime of the temporary as needed for the binding; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47662488/6820433) for details.

> Why is there such difference between before and after adding `impl Drop`?

See [this comment](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough-with-destructor/7716/11). The extended lifetime of the temporary matches the lifetime of `x` in your example. When a `struct` containing references has no `Drop` implementation,

> it’s permissible for reference and referent to have identical lifetimes: the reference can’t be used unsafely. Introducing a `Drop` impl to the situation requires the referent to *strictly* outlive the reference, to ensure there is a clear order in which to run `drop` methods.

Comment: The answer to the first question is incorrect. In the given context there is no [lifetime extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension). The reason this works anyway is [constant promotion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/destructors.html#constant-promotion) – `Nil` gets promoted to a static constant, so the reference has static lifetime.