# Initialising an array of mutable reference to struct

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrowing

I have `struct Board` which contains an element `rows: [[&'a mut Tile; 7];7]`

I have no idea how to initialise that by a constructor in `impl Board {}` block because of lifetimes, so I've tried to initialise it in the `main` function.

Sadly, `rows = [[&mut Tile::def(); 7]; 7]` doesn't work because Rust wants to copy the reference `&mut Tile::def()`. (Where `Tile::def()` is a constructor for `Tile`).

Is there a way to initialise this array such that every element (i,j) is a reference to a distinct `Tile`?

Currently, the only solution that works is

```
let mut rows = [[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()]];

let board = Board { rows : rows, ...};
```

which is unsatisfactory for obvious reasons.

What I have tried was creating a function that transforms `[[Tile; 7]; 7]` into the desired array, but I encountered impossibility of borrowing mutably elements of this array multiple times.

Comment: Why `&'a mut` at all? Make rows own the Tile, that would be the proper way.

Comment: We have too few information about your needs.

Comment: @hellow I want `&` because I want to cheaply swap tiles in the board and `mut` because Tiles may be modified. I've implemented a version with `rows` owning Tiles, but thought it's to high performance cost as tiles are swapped frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&mut` is not just "a pointer with mutation". It's a *borrow*. That means it can't *own* the `Tile`, which has to belong somewhere else.

This approach

```
let mut rows = [[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()],[&mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def(), &mut Tile::def()]];
```

works because each individual `Tile::def()` creates a new, temporary `Tile`, and the `&mut` causes the temporary to be "promoted" to the stack -- see [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662253/why-is-it-legal-to-borrow-a-temporary) for more information. But it's not the way you should fix this problem: you need something to *own* the `Tile`s.

You could, for instance, create a `Vec<Tile>` and fill `rows` with references to the members of the `Vec`. But that doesn't solve your initialization problem, and the real answer is easier: you want an *owning* pointer, so use `Box<Tile>` instead of `&mut Tile`.

`Box` doesn't implement `Copy`, but it does implement another trait that makes this job much easier: `Default`.

```
impl Default for Tile {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Tile::def()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut rows: [[Box<Tile>; 7]; 7] = Default::default();
}
```

Depending on what `Tile::def` does, you may also be able to `#[derive(Default)]` instead of implementing it by hand.

---

There's one other option I encourage you to consider: Store all the `Tile`s in a `Vec`, but refer to them by indices instead of any kind of pointer. It's cheap to swap two indices, it's easy to grow the `Vec` if you need to, it makes it possible to store `rows` alongside its backing store without lifetime issues, and it's more cache-friendly (which may mean better performance) than storing all the `Tile`s in separate allocations. But it's not necessarily ideal in all situations.