# Is there one-line syntax for constructing a struct that contains a reference to a temporary?

Tags: struct, rust, borrow-checker

Consider the following invalid Rust code. There is one struct `Foo` that contains a reference to a second struct `Bar`:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a Bar,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn new(bar: &'a Bar) -> Foo<'a> {
        Foo { bar }
    }
}

struct Bar {
    value: String,
}

impl Bar {
    fn empty() -> Bar {
        Bar {
            value: String::from("***"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::new(&Bar::empty());
    println!("{}", foo.bar.value);
}
```

The compiler does not like this:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:24:25
   |
24 |     let foo = Foo::new(&Bar::empty());
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                         |
   |                         creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
25 |     println!("{}", foo.bar.value);
   |                    ------------- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

I can make it work by doing what the compiler says - using a `let` binding:

```
fn main() {
    let bar = &Bar::empty();
    let foo = Foo::new(bar);
    println!("{}", foo.bar.value);
}
```

However, suddenly I need two lines for something as trivial as instantiating my `Foo`. Is there any simple way to fix this in a one-liner?

Comment: Who is supposed to own the `Bar` in `Foo::new(&Bar::empty())`? The `Foo` struct doesn't own it, it only references it. Are you sure that you wanted a `&'a Bar`, and not just `Bar`, or something like `Box<Bar>`, or `Rc<Bar>`? Currently, your `Foo` has no raison d'être without a `Bar`, therefore you cannot instantiate a `Foo` without having a `Bar` in scope.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin There will be a parent struct owning both the bar and the foos referencing it. So foos will be spawned from the parent struct with a reference to the bar. However, when I am writing tests I want to create a lot of foos with a throwaway dummy bar, and I find my code for doing that gets very convoluted.

Comment: Maybe it's noteworthy that both `let foo = Foo { bar: &Bar::empty() };` and `println!("{}", Foo::new(&Bar::empty()).bar.value);` work, because *"If you immediately assign the reference to a variable in a let statement (or make it part of some struct or array that is being immediately assigned), then Rust makes the [referenced] anonymous variable live as long as the variable the let initializes [...] Otherwise, the anonymous variable lives to the end of the enclosing statement"* (Blandy, Orendorff). Especially the second part seems useful for short `assert` statements.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, I need to use the `new` constructor. And doing the construction in the same line of code as the struct is used is usually not feasible since it may be used in multiple assertions etc. So I guess I will have to use a separate `let ` statement to create the bar.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin By the way, I still think your comment qualifies as a good answer to my question so feel free to post it as such.

Comment: @Anders if this is sufficiently annoying, you could create a simple macro to have a shorter syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such syntax, other than what you have typed.

For the details of how long a temporary lives when you take a reference to it, see:

- [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/155423)

---

> There will be a parent struct owning both the `bar` and the `foo`s referencing it.

Good luck:

- [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)

Comment: Now that NLL are stable, has anybody investigated whether it is a good idea to extend the lifetime of temporaries?

Comment: @starblue to be honest, I thought that [making the functions in question const](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=210bc4497f0ee6d9e01619fcb60517c9) would allow this to work, but it doesn't (yet?)

Comment: @starblue ah, that was [deliberately restricted](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/53851), so it's possible it might work in the future. I think it's orthogonal to NLL though.