# Why does this iterator drop when not called directly as a function argument?

Tags: rust

I'm confused about Rust's behavior in the following example.

This example fails:

```
let mut coll = vec![1, 2, 3].iter();
some_consuming_fn(&mut coll);
```

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:4:20
  |
4 |     let mut coll = vec![1, 2, 3].iter();
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^       - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                    |
  |                    creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
5 |     some_consuming_fn(&mut coll);
  |                       --------- borrow later used here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

However, if you call the iterable conversion as a function argument everything works fine.

```
let coll = vec![1, 2, 3];
some_consuming_fn(&mut coll.iter());
```

I'm confused about the ownership rules of a collection that's been turned into an iterable. Why would a call to `some_iterable.iter()` drop immediately after being called?

For reference, `some_consuming_fn` has the signature:

```
some_consuming_fn(x: &mut Iter<u32>) -> Foo;
```

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/155423). If you disagree, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Yes, that question answers this one.

Comment: _I'm confused about the ownership rules of a collection that's been turned into an iterable._ -- calling `.iter()` does not turn it into an iterator, it returns an iterator that references the original. `.into_iter()` actually turns it into an iterator that owns the collection - you can use that instead.