# If I want to pass a default value for an environment variable to `unwrap_or`, why do I need to pass a `String` and not `&str`?

Tags: rust

I am trying to parse an environment value; using `std::env` as follows

```
let environment = env::var("APP_ENV").unwrap();
```

This returns a string to the variable `environment`. If I want to pass a default value, then I have to use the below code

```
let environment = env::var("APP_ENV").unwrap_or("development".into());
```

but I was expecting to do it like

```
let environment = env::var("APP_ENV").unwrap_or("development");
```

as mentioned in the Rust [example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or)

But then it shows error `String expected but found &str`

Why is that error not happening in the example code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between Rust's \`String\` and \`str\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)

Comment: It's better to use `.unwrap_or_else(|| "development".into())`, so the default string isn't allocated if the environment variable is present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Rust, string literals are of type `&str`, and environment variables are of type `String`. Essentially, `&str`s have a fixed size, while `String`s can be dynamically changed and resized (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)). `unwrap_or` requires that the alternate value be of the same type as the option value, which means that you must provide a `String` to match the type of the environment variable. That's why you have to call `.into` to convert it to a string. In their example, the option uses a string literal, which is also of type `&str`, so there are no errors.

Comment: "In Rust, string literals are of type &str, and environment variables are of type String. "  complement: envvars are `String` because the unix `getenv` is super unsafe, it returns a pointer into the "environment data" buffer so the pointer can be invalidated at essentially any point. Therefore Rust immediately copies that data into an owned buffer (an `OsString`), and optionally decodes it to a "proper" String for convenience (`env::var_os` provides access to the "raw" data even if it's not valid unicode).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need ownership over the owned string, you can use [`as_deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.as_deref) to convert it to a string slice. This allows you to provide a matching default value in [`unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or) as (static) string slice to avoid allocation.

```rs
let environment = std::env::var("APP_ENV").as_deref().unwrap_or("development");
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work yet because the compiler (too) smartly drops the owned value early since it can't be accessed after the conversion. But the compiler's error message is helpful and suggests a separate variable declaration to prevent this.

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:2:23
  |
2 |     let environment = std::env::var("APP_ENV").as_deref().unwrap_or("development");
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                    - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                       |
  |                       creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
3 |     println!("{}", environment);
  |                    ----------- borrow later used here
  |
help: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
  |
2 ~     let binding = std::env::var("APP_ENV");
3 ~     let environment = binding.as_deref().unwrap_or("development");
  |

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0716`.
```

Further using variable shadowing to prevent creating another identifier, you can use:

```rs
let environment = env::var("APP_ENV");
let environment = environment.as_deref().unwrap_or("development");
```

Note: For an unwrapped owned string you can avoid the extra declaration by using the reference operator together with the range operator instead of `as_deref()` because the reference operator prevents the compiler from dropping the owned value early. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent trick for wrapped `Result` or `Option` types.

```rs
let foo = &String::from("foo")[..];
```

See also:

- [Idiomatic way to set string default value to unwrap](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/idiomatic-way-to-set-string-default-value-to-unwrap/29228/7)
- [String slice vs as_ref](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/string-slice-vs-as-ref/21707)
- [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662253/why-is-it-legal-to-borrow-a-temporary/50818789)