# Rust Double Reference Value

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker, ownership, borrowing

Looking through the blurz bluetooth library for Rust.

There is a variable declared with a value equal to a reference of a temp value(?).

This value is then passed into another function by reference.

**How is ownership handled for a variable set to the value of a reference in a single statement and what does it mean to then use that reference as a reference?**

Example:

```rust
let bt_session = &Session::create_session(None)?;
let adapter: Adapter = Adapter::init(bt_session)?;
adapter.set_powered(true)?;

let session = DiscoverySession::create_session(
    &bt_session,
    adapter.get_id()
)?;
```

See variable `bt_session`.

[Source code example link](https://github.com/szeged/blurz/blob/master/examples/test6.rs).

Comment: Can you clarify your questions? "How does x work?" is kinda ambiguous. Can you explain what you find wrong or confusing about the shared code example?

Comment: tried to update the question but really, the syntax is unclear to me what the borrowing implications are and reference tree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662253/why-is-it-legal-to-borrow-a-temporary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A commented example to illustrate some concepts:

```rust
use rand;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Struct {
    id: i32
}

impl Drop for Struct {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // print when struct is dropped
        println!("dropped {:?}", self);
    }
}

fn rand_struct() -> Struct {
    Struct { id: rand::random() }
}

/*
this does not compile:

fn rand_struct_ref<'a>() -> &'a Struct {
    &rand_struct()
    // struct dropped here so we can't return it to caller's scope
}
*/

fn takes_struct_ref(s: &Struct) {}

fn main() {
    // brings struct into scope and immediately creates ref to it
    // this is okay because the struct is not dropped until end of this scope
    let s = &rand_struct();
    
    println!("holding ref to {:?}", s);
    
    // all these work because of deref coercion
    takes_struct_ref(s);
    takes_struct_ref(&s);
    takes_struct_ref(&&s);
    
    // struct dropped here
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea9810d95f8a16c66b0e6d9682f87dfe)

To answer your first question: You can't return a reference from a function if the underlying value is dropped at the end of the function but it's okay to immediately make a reference to a returned value since that value lives for the rest of the caller's scope. You can see this in action if you run the above example, as `holding ref to Struct { id: <id> }` will get printed before `dropped Struct { id: <id> }`.

To answer your second question: the reason you can pass an `&Struct` or an `&&Struct` or an `&&&Struct` and so on to function which only takes an `&Struct` is because of a Rust syntax sugar feature called *deref coercion* which automatically derefs variables when they are used as function arguments or as part of method calls. In your shared code examples *it looks like* a ref of a ref is being passed to the function *but actually* it's just passing a single ref after auto deref coercion takes place.

See also

- [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/2766908)
- [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/2766908)

Comment: so is the entire purpose of the &s argument for clarity? is there ever a reason to use && or &&&?

Comment: You would have to use && or &&& if the function (for whatever reason) specifically expected an && or &&&. Also, I wouldn't say you should write &s when the function expects a ref if s is already a ref. I don't know why test6 does that but my best guess is the author was refactoring some code and forgot to drop the unnecessary & in front of the variable.

Comment: thank you for the well thought out response plus example and sharing some intuition, this makes a lot more sense now.