# Why does borrowing this temporary value work?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, temporary

I'm reading the Rust Programming Language book. In [Chapter 15.4](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html) it says:

> The borrow checker wouldn’t let us compile `let a = Cons(10, &Nil);` for example, because the temporary `Nil` value would be dropped before `a` could take a reference to it.

I have tried to create the `Cons` list with references like below, and it works for me. Why does this work when the book says it shouldn't?

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum List<'a> {
    Cons(i32, &'a List<'a>),
    Nil,
}

use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let a = Cons(10, &Nil);
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Comment: There's no reference counting in this program, FYI.

Comment: Related: [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662253/why-is-it-legal-to-borrow-a-temporary)

Comment: @JohnKugelman thanks for the edit!! But yeah, I am still confused why the above snippet works though.

Comment: Voting to close this as a duplicate. Unfortunately, the accepted (and only) answer to the duplicate question is incorrect, but I added a comment there.