# error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed (simple struct example)

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker

Currently, I'm learning the **Lifetimes** topic in Rust.
And I kind of get it, but recently I've came across this simple code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    val: i32
}

fn main() {
    let a:&Test;
    let b = 32;

    a = &Test {
        val: b
    };

    println!("{:?}", a.val);
}
```

But it won't compile, with the respective error provided:

> error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed

I know how to fix it & I do understand, that a temporary was created at line 10 and will be destroyed at the end of the statement at line 12.
*(also the compiler itself states the same)*

What I don't understand, it's why the following code actually will compile?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    val: i32
}

fn main() {
    let a:&Test;
    let b = 32;

    a = &Test {
        val: 5
    };

    println!("{:?}", a.val);
}
```

Only struct initialization values has been changed.
The `val` was `b` and now it's `5`.

My guess is that the value of `b`, which is now owned by `val` field of our struct instance will be dropped at the end of the statement.
And therefore we will end up with the dangling reference.

Oh ... and one more interesting example.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    val: i32
}

fn main() {
    let a:&Test;
    let b = 32;

    let a = &Test {
        val: b
    };

    println!("{:?}", a.val);
}
```

This will also successfully compile.
It's the same as the first example, but we shadowing the `a` variable with `let`.

So, my fellow rustaceans ... why it's working this way?

Comment: You have a misconheption about where the temporary gets dropped. In simple cases like this Rust constructs an inaccessible temporary variable which is dropped at the end of the scope, not at the end of the statement.

Comment: For now I can only close vote: Does this answer your question? [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662253/why-is-it-legal-to-borrow-a-temporary)

Comment: @cafce25 No, it doesn't.

Comment: @AbrahamTugalov Why not?

Comment: best way to learn rust is to ignore lifetime until you really really need them, and this would come only after code in rust for 2 years and you want code a library

Answer (score -3):

## Case 1

```rust
    a = &Test { val: b };
    println!("{a:?}");
```

Let's call this one the base case. No "magic" happens, the temporary value is dropped at the end of the statement, and the compiler complains "temporary value dropped while borrowed".

## Case 2

```rust
    a = &Test { val: 5 };
    println!("{a:?}");
```

The key difference here is we now have a constant expression due to the literal `5`, so it is eligible for [constant promotion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#constant-promotion):

> Promotion of a value expression to a `'static` slot occurs when the expression could be written in a constant and borrowed, and that borrow could be dereferenced where the expression was originally written, without changing the runtime behavior.

## Case 3

```rust
    let a = &Test { val: b };
    println!("{a:?}");
```

Finally, here we have a `let` statement, which is eligible for [temporary lifetime extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension). According to the reference,

> The temporary scopes for expressions in let statements are sometimes extended to the scope of the block containing the let statement

but also,

> The exact rules for temporary lifetime extension are subject to change. This is describing the current behavior only

Evidently, temporary lifetime extension for `let` statements doesn't occur when the `let` statement is separated from its initializer.