# Rust : drop(&RefMut) instead of drop(RefMut)?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, refcell

I know when borrowing a value from a `RefCell`, I can manually drop it to end this borrow.

However, if I use the reference to a `RefMut` instead of directly using the `RefMut`, the drop trait seems invalid to end this borrow.

So, what happend when trying to drop the `&RefMut` ? and why the `RefMut` will not be dropped during this operation. If the referenced `RefMut` is not dropped, when will it be dropped ?

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Data {
    pub x: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let c = RefCell::new(Data { x: 42 });
    let b = &c.borrow_mut();
    drop(b);
    let mut d = c.borrow_mut();
    d.x = 43;
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

output

```bash
thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError', src/main.rs:11:19
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References can only exist if the value they reference also exists somewhere. In C/C++ it would be undefined behaviour to create a reference to a temporary that doesn't get stored in a variable. In Rust, however, it is legal, and an invisible variable gets created in the background that lives until the end of the current scope. This is called [temporary lifetime extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension). More info can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662253/why-is-it-legal-to-borrow-a-temporary).

You can limit its lifetime by introducing another scope:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Data {
    pub x: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let c = RefCell::new(Data { x: 42 });
    {
        let b = &c.borrow_mut();
        drop(b);
    }
    let mut d = c.borrow_mut();
    d.x = 43;
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

```
Hello, world!
```

Or by storing it in a named variable instead:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Data {
    pub x: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let c = RefCell::new(Data { x: 42 });

    let b_val = c.borrow_mut();
    let b = &b_val;
    drop(b);
    drop(b_val);

    let mut d = c.borrow_mut();
    d.x = 43;
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

```rust
Hello, world!
```