# Rust Ownership of Borrowed Struct

Tags: rust

My goal is to understand the difference between instances of structs themselves — a la `rect1: Rectangle` — and "borrowed pointer" type instances — `rect2: &Rectangle`. My understanding is that using a raw `self` in `into_area` will cause ownership to be transferred to "the struct," presumably *away from* `main()`. It is this ownership transfer that I am trying to grok.

```rust
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

impl Rectangle {
    fn into_area(self) -> u32 {
        self.width * self.height
    }
}

fn main() {
    let rect1: Rectangle = Rectangle {
        width: 90,
        height: 10,
    };

    let rect2: &Rectangle = &Rectangle {
        width: 15,
        height: 10,
    };

    let area1 = rect1.into_area();

    println!("rect1 area1: {}", area1);

    // E0382
    let _temp1 = rect1;

    // E0507
    let area2 = rect2.into_area();

    println!("rect2 area2: {}", area2);

    // No error given by compiler.
    let _temp2 = rect2;
}
```

When I call `rect1.into_area()`, ownership is moved. An area is computed and returned to the caller, and the `Rectangle` instance then gets freed. If I try to then make use of `rect1` again in `main()`, via `_temp1`, then the compiler complains that ownership has moved. That much makes sense.

However, I suppose I do not understand who "owns" the borrowed pointer type of `rect2`. I thought that `main()` would own it, and that there would be similar behaviour as with `rect1`, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Instead I get E0507 immediately upon calling `rect2.into_area()`:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*rect2` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:31:17
   |
31 |     let area2 = rect2.into_area();
   |                 ^^^^^^-----------
   |                 |     |
   |                 |     `*rect2` moved due to this method call
   |                 move occurs because `*rect2` has type `Rectangle`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
note: `Rectangle::into_area` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `*rect2`
  --> src/main.rs:7:18
   |
7  |     fn into_area(self) -> u32 {
   |                  ^^^^
```

Why can't I transfer ownership of a shared reference in this case, like was done for `rect1`? Presumably, there is only one "share" of the reference: the declaration of `rect2` in `main()`. Is it a matter of the compiler not being able to infer that? Am I simply "holding it wrong" by conjuring a silly usage of `&` that isn't how it's usually done?

I've tried reading over section four of the Rust Book. I also investigated the particular error via `rustc --explain E0507`, which has this to say:

> To fix this error, you have three choices:
>
> - Try to avoid moving the variable.
> - Somehow reclaim the ownership.
> - Implement the `Copy` trait on the type.

I suppose using raw `self` in `into_area` precludes the first option, leaving options two and three. Implementing the `Copy` trait is simple enough, but what would "Somehow reclaim the ownership" look like in this scenario? I'm assuming that, once the area is computed and returned to the caller, that the instance is freed/destroyed, meaning it's not possible to "somehow reclaim the ownership."

Comment: Borrowing a temporary like you do creates an inaccessible owner, you can never move if all you have is a reference. See [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662253/why-is-it-legal-to-borrow-a-temporary)

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment and link, @cafce25 . That all makes sense to me now :)